# How can I create my own class of objects using SilverLight

Tags: c#, asp.net, silverlight, silverlight-4.0, silverlight-3.0

Can someone help me to resolve a question: How can I create my own class of objects (using SilverLight), which will consist of figures, such as a circle with 4 buttons: bottom, top, left and right inside the circle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to add a silverlight user control to your project and to define its content.

There's a tutorial [here](http://www.insidercoding.com/post/2008/07/14/Tutorial-Creating-a-User-Control-in-Silverlight-20.aspx) for SL2 but it's still relevant for SL4.

Comment: Is it possible to create figure immediately with buttons? @vc 74

Comment: Not sure I understand your question but SL pages are user controls themselves so you're free to add any kind of control to them.

Comment: This solution will be useful if it is possible to generate a new instance of this control on the page when you click the left mouse button for example. @ vc 74

Comment: @revolutionkpi, Yes, you can dynamically add user controls to a page. You just need to instanciate the control and call Children.Add on the parent

Comment: Maybe it is a simple, but can you show me the example of generating a new instance of this control, I will be very grateful @vc

Comment: Provided you are in one of the page's methods: MyUserControl control = new MyUserControl(); Children.Add(control);